# How to load only specific functions from a package

Tags: r

I have a package that uses the trim() function in the gdata package. I literally use nothing else from the package and (as some of you may have seen) it overwrites some functionality of base R that I need.

Is there a way to load only one function rather than the whole package?

Comment: why not `trim <- gdata::trim` ?

Comment: Doesn't that assume the `gdata` is loaded in order to be able to do that?

Comment: The downside of @mplourde's method is that if you ever post your package to CRAN, folks who download it won't get `gdata` automatically downloaded for them if they don't already have it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure. Just use an `importFrom` directive in your NAMESPACE file ([as described here in  R-exts](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Specifying-imports-and-exports)).

```
importFrom(gdata, trim)
```

---

OP EDIT: As of R 3.2.0 there's now a base function: `trimws()`

Answer (score -1):

Now I get it:  from another post:  It means the package (In this case R) can access the package functions/objects, but the user can not without explicitly loading the tools package where as stats, graphics, etc. are loaded and ready to go for the user.

So -- the formally specified import (in which you specify 'Imports: survival' in the description file and also 'importFrom(survival, Surv)' in the NAMESPACE file does indeed work, but then, without also *adding* 'Surv' to the list of  'export' -ed objects, the function
'Surv' is only available to the code inside the package but not to the user (and hence not available to examples in vignettes either).

Comment: so in the NAMESPACE file add Surv to your list of exports:   export("Surv", ...)