# Using single functions from a package

Tags: r, namespaces, package

Using individual functions from an unloaded  package

As time has gone by I find myself loading more and more packages at the beginning of an R session. Just loading the tidyverse loads more packages than used to be my norm. Because of this, I find myself increasingly likely to be hit by function name conflicts. Especially when I did not notice those conflicts during package loading these can create confusing results and strange errors. So I am wondering if I can, in general, just import the particular function I want to use, without loading the package from which it comes.

More precisely, if `this_pack` is a package that is locally installed but not loaded, and `this_fn()` is an exported function in this_pack, can I safely expect `this_pack::this_fn()` to work, and to work in the same way as it would if the entire package were loaded? I know it usually does, but I want to know if there are times I should expect it to fail.

See the answers to related questions for additional information:

- [Is it a good practice to call functions in a package via ::](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232791/is-it-a-good-practice-to-call-functions-in-a-package-via)
- [Load a package apart from one function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52938644/load-a-package-apart-from-one-function)

I've accepted the answer of user2554330, which I think would not be an answer to the other questions referenced. Still, they provide interesting, and related, information on other reasons to or not to use ::, so I think keeping the cross-reference is probably a good idea. I've incorporated them above.

Comment: The edge case is if that function calls another function that has a name conflict if the package maintainer there has not namespaced the functions used.   That can cause problems though it is possible to get around them by importing them yourself. @DJV I don't think that's an exact duplicate.

Comment: @Elin, you're right, it's not an exact duplicate. I removed it. However, to some extent, I think it might answer some of the OP questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232791/is-it-a-good-practice-to-call-functions-in-a-package-via

Comment: Check out this related question: [«Load a package apart from one function»](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52938644/9406040).

Comment: To pythonify your imports, see [import](https://github.com/smbache/import) or [modules](https://github.com/klmr/modules)

Comment: As for `::` failing, it really shouldn't, but occasionally does. One cause is package authors putting code in `.onAttach` that should be in `.onLoad`, or otherwise aggressively messing with the user environment. That shouldn't be too common, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load a package apart from one function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52938644/load-a-package-apart-from-one-function)

Comment: @Roman I think this is the inverse of the question you link to.

Comment: @RomanLustrik The title of the question is misleading. Check out the OP + answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, nowadays it should always be safe to call `this_pack::this_fn()`.  If `this_pack` was not loaded, this will load it (all of it). (Remember that loading and attaching a package are different!  Loading it gets it in memory, but not on the search list.  Attaching it puts it on the search list.)  This may make the first call a little slow, but the package will stay loaded, so subsequent calls will be faster.  It used to be the case that evaluating `::` took a noticeable amount of time in every call, but I think just-in-time compiling has mostly removed that.  But if you want, you can get a local copy using

```
local_copy <- this_pack::this_fn
```

and then make calls to `local_copy()` without paying for the `::` lookup again.

Since all packages have namespaces, any calls made by `this_pack::this_fn()` (or `local_copy()`) will go to the right place, unless the author of the package tries really hard to subvert the normal mechanisms.

If you are writing a package yourself, you can import just that one function.  This will mean that loading your package will trigger a load of `this_pack`:  so your load will be a bit slower, but the first call to `this_fn()` will be faster.

Comment: this is a great answer, that answers more questions than I even knew I was ignorent about. In particular,  although I knew about the difference between loading and attaching, I never actually did one without the other intentionally, or knew why I would. This makes it clear that I have already been doing sp without knowing it, and that I had a good reason to, without knowing that either, and finally, that I surely will many times in the future, except now I will know what I am doing and why. Bravo!